# Grouping gridview with MS SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, gridview

How do I group my items from a table in MS SQL ?

[I had been looking on this guide here](http://technico.qnownow.com/grouping-gridview-wpf/) there is some issues with

```
 DataManager.RetrieveProductsbySubCat().Tables[0].DefaultView
```

> The name 'DataManager' does not exist in the current context

and

```
 string connString =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sql"];
```

> The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context*

You should add 
`using System.Configuration;`

DataManager should be in *Microsoft.CommerceServer.Marketing*, so add using for that one as well.

Comment: using System.Configuration; 
didn't solved it 
and Microsoft.CommerceServer.Marketing is that a refference or a dll?

Comment: I have checked the URL that you shared with us, and based on this
_DataManager.RetrieveProductsbySubCat().Tables[0].DefaultView;_

DataManager should be the class where you put **RetrieveProductsbySubCat** method.

Do you get "ConfigurationManager" issue during the compile?
Can you check if System.Configuration is referenced into your project?

Comment: yeah System.Configuration was not referenced so that fixed it
and i changed public mainwindow() out with public ProductsBySubCategory()
and still getting an issue with DataManager

Comment: OK, if ProductsBySubCategory() method is in the same class like mainwindow() then you don't need DataManager.

Comment: i wonder if the ps. and p. in the string sql is the short name for the table? as they are called Production.Product and Production.ProductSubCategory and the columns names in the table dont have ps. and p. do you know that?

Comment: ps and p are aliases in SQL query. You can add alias for each table in you query. They are really useful when you have same column name in both tables and want to query them both.